# How To Render and store WP Data From Local System

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I have a Wordpress website,

1. which contains more than 100,000 posts.
2. this is an informative site.
3. Data does not change once entered into the system.

**Problem**

As data is so much so it requires good server configuration to process the data, which is really costly for me. Right now the website is not popular so its out of my budget to keep it running with such a huge price.

Right now the DB is on AWS RDS and it has 4GB of Ram.

**Query**

Is there any way that I can store all the data on users local machine so I dont need to hit the DB again and again.

I have little idea that redux does it, but not sure if this is possible or not. Any other idea would also be appreciated.

Comment: Moving static assets such as CSS, JS, Images, etc. will offload processing from the website (which is a good idea in many ways) but will have no effect on your database unless you are storing some of these objects in the database (move them out). Depending on the variety of queries, you could add a caching plugin for WordPress to reduce the load on the database. This would move some of the load from the database to the website at the expense of memory on the web server (meaning if the web server is tiny with no free memory, caching will not help).

Comment: If this was my website and I really needed to conserve money, I would pick an instance type with 4 GB of memory, install MySQL and merge the website and RDS together. This has higher risk than using RDS but with reduced cost.

Answer (score 1):

If the website is static, the content can be offloaded to Amazon S3. This can provide much lower-cost hosting because Wordpress and the database only need to be turned on when adding new content.

Search the web for some solutions, such as:

- [amazon s3 | WordPress.org](https://wordpress.org/plugins/tags/amazon-s3/)
- [How to move WordPress images to Amazon S3 – Free Solution! – Jozef Jarosciak Blog](https://www.joe0.com/2017/03/13/how-to-move-wordpress-images-to-amazon-s3-free-solution/)
- [Moving WordPress Media To The Cloud With Amazon S3 - WPMU DEV](https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/moving-wordpress-media-to-amazon-s3/)

Comment: Thanks for your reply guys.
there is 1 more thing guys.
The website does not have any image or media, it only has text content.
the website is a combination of files and text content.
For files I'm using free ec2 instance of AWS
for DB I'm using RDS with 4GB Ram. so I'm not sure what I need to put on S3.

Comment: My suggestion was that you can output from Wordpress to S3, then shutdown your Wordpress system (except for when you wish to create/edit posts). Very low cost.